# How to write summary data for two Keras models to their own files/folders?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorboard, tensorflow2.0

I'm recording some custom metrics for my Tensorflow model like this:

```
# Setup
metric_writer = tf.summary.create_file_writer("{}\\train".format(log_dir))
metric_writer.set_as_default()

# During training write the score
tf.summary.scalar("score", score, step=episode)
```

This all works fine, I can see my data in Tensorboard as I want. However I now want to run two models in my process and have their data recorded to separate files/folders so I can easily compare them. However since writing the data is done with `tf.summary.scalar` which doesn't have (or accept) any reference to the model or the writer, I can't figure out how to write to two different files/folders (one for each model).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use two separate `tf.SummaryWriter` s and their respective context managers. Except taken from [tensorflow documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/beta/guide/effective_tf2):

```
summary_writer = tf.summary.create_file_writer('/tmp/summaries')
with summary_writer.as_default():
  tf.summary.scalar('loss', 0.1, step=42)
```

This way you can control which summary writer is used.

Comment: Aha, perfect - thanks! I was scanning that page not so long ago, not sure how I missed that :-)